# I have to fill out and sign a PDF electronically but I only have Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe

Is there another tool I can use for this?

I have to fill out a PDF that has pre-defined text fields and a spot where you can sign (but I think you need to do one of those PDF electronic signatures), and then click Submit to send the form.

However I only have Adobe Reader which doesn't allow for me to sign the document, and I don't think I can install software on this computer due to rights privileges being tight. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Make your PDFs *Reader-enabled*. A PDF that is *Reader-enabled* is signed using a private key owned by Adobe. When Adobe Reader can validate that signature, it unlocks functionality in Adobe Reader that is usually available in Adobe Acrobat only. Making a document *Reader-enabled* is (obviously) only possible if you have Adobe software (Adobe Acrobat, Adobe LiveCycle ES). You won't find any third party software that can do this, because no third party has the right to use Adobe's private key.
2. Use a third party viewer that is able to edit form fields. For instance: http://jpedal.org, http://www.foxitsoftware.com/, http://www.nitropdf.com/

**Disclaimer:** it isn't clear what you mean by signing. In Europe, you need a private key (on a smart card, an USB token,...) to create a digital signature. In the US, people call any scribble a digital signature. Some viewers will allow you to add some hand-written signature, but in Europe that isn't considered being a legally binding digital signature.

Comment: I am filling out a tax form here in the States so there's literally a line on the form where I am supposed to sign, but I can't just type my name in -- so I think I have to put a physical signature on the line somehow and then send this form off with the embedded Submit button

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of the signature field? Is the PDF Reader-enabled?

Comment: @KaliMa if it is a tax Form, please provide a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout services like [Docusign](https://www.docusign.com). If I am not mistaken, Docusign lets you upload a PDF and sign it using just your browser. They do have a free trial option.